# Firefox catching of keydown events after page load

Tags: javascript, firefox, events

I've found a weird behavior in Firefox. I'm catching `keydown` events on my website and in Firefox, after the page loads, I can catch these event without no problems as long as they are not firefox reserved shortcuts.

Let's say the reserved shortcut is `ctrl + a`.

After the page loads, I can perform `ctrl + a` once, then if I perform it again, Firefox takes over and executes the shortcut. If I click into the page, Firefox does nothing and the event gets captured. If I load the page and click into the page straightaway, every event gets captured properly without Firefox intervening.

The issue is happening only if I don't click into the page - in that case Firefox seems to take over on it's own. `preventDefault(), stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation()` don't seem to help.

Comment: You may not have any control over this. The browser decides whether a key event is passed into the page or consumed by the browser interface. You can't take control of the event until the browser decides to pass it to the page.

Comment: @Ouroborus I thought that could be the case.. I could get around it with some FF extension but that's not a very nice solution. Thanks anyways for the comment